# Why these strings don't concatanate and print?

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I'm new to C++ and was learning about string concepts and was just experimenting around.
I have the following code:

```
int main(){

    string s1="loc";
    string s2="al var";
    
    cout<<s1.append(s2)<<endl<<s1<<endl<<s1+s2;    
}
```

Running it in Vs-code I get the output as:

```
local var
local var
local var
```

What I don't understand is I append s1 with s2 and it prints as "local var".
Then I print **s1** and get the output **"local var"** meaning **s1** is updated successfully.
But when I print **s1+s2** I don't know why it still gives the same output as **s1** and **s2** isn't being concatenated with s1 in the output.
I was expecting answer as **"local varal var**.
I want to know about how and why is this happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using when you compile?

Comment: In the old days, there was no guarantee of the order in which the pieces were gathered before sending them off to be printed. This was fixed in C++17

Comment: Sounds kinda insane, huh? People put up with this because it allowed compilers the leeway to generate more efficient programs.. Eventually it <expletive deleted>ed over enough people or the performance difference was so weak that the rules  changed to provide a nice, predicable order. [For this and a few other cases at least](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: @user4581301  Thanks I'm using the C++14 version. I guess updating it to C++17 will fix it.